# Is it safe to try Ubuntu 14.1 on a Macbook Pro (late 2013)?

Tags: unity-dash

I have the latest Ubuntu on my desktop machine. I wanted to use the "Try Ubuntu" feature on a Macbook Pro (late 2013) but I don't want to screw up my MBP. Is their anyone using the "Try Ubuntu" feature? Does it screw up anything on booting?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: I definitely don't expect the "Try Ubuntu" to change anything on the machine (at least by itself) - but that is only my **opinion**.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience having installed dozens of different operating systems and "Trying Ubuntu" on dozens of hardware combinations. I believe I can safely say that it isn't possible to damage your hardware with the "Try Ubuntu" option. Note that this doesn't mean it's impossible to damage your current operating system by doing something ill-advised such as deleting or editing files off of your hard drive that are required by you existing MAC OS. Provided you avoid mounting the MAC drive under Ubuntu you should not be able to damage anything.

Source: Experience